# Chart.js time interval as bars

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Is it possible to make a time interval using Chart.js? As far as I'm concerned, using stacked bars chart is the closest I can get but not quite what I want
What I'm trying to achieve is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itoSM.png) time interval
Here's the code

```
    const data = {
      labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed' ],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Bars',
        data: [
            [14, 16],
            [17, 22],
            [13, 19],
        ],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)',
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)',
        ],
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderSkipped: false
      }]
    };

    const config = {
      type: 'bar',
      data,
      options: {
        indexAxis: 'y',
        scales: {
          x: {
            min: 12,
            max: 26,
            ticks: {
                stepSize: 1,
                callback: (val, index) => {
                    return `${String(val % 24).padStart(2, '0')}:00`
                }
            },
          },
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      }
    };

    const myChart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('myChart'),
      config
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use horizontalBar for your bar type.  Example:

```
{
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
  labels: ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"],
  datasets: [{
    axis: 'y',
    label: 'My First Dataset',
    data: [[5,65], [30,90], [20,80], [15,71], [20,56], [24,55], [15,70]],
    fill: false,
    backgroundColor: [
      'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
      'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
      'rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)',
      'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
      'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
      'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
      'rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)'
    ],
    borderColor: [
      'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
      'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
      'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
      'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
      'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
      'rgb(201, 203, 207)'
    ],
    borderWidth: 1
  }]
},
  options: {
    indexAxis: 'y',
     scales: {
            x: {
                stacked: true
            },
            y: {
                stacked: true
            }
        }
  }
}
```

here the [result](https://quickchart.io/chart?c=%7B%0A%20%20type%3A%20%27horizontalBar%27%2C%0A%20%20data%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20labels%3A%20%5B%22a%22%2C%22b%22%2C%22c%22%2C%22d%22%2C%22e%22%2C%22f%22%2C%22g%22%5D%2C%0A%20%20datasets%3A%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20axis%3A%20%27y%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20label%3A%20%27My%20First%20Dataset%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%5B%5B5%2C65%5D%2C%20%5B30%2C90%5D%2C%20%5B20%2C80%5D%2C%20%5B15%2C71%5D%2C%20%5B20%2C56%5D%2C%20%5B24%2C55%5D%2C%20%5B15%2C70%5D%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20fill%3A%20false%2C%0A%20%20%20%20backgroundColor%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%27rgba(255%2C%2099%2C%20132%2C%200.2)%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%27rgba(255%2C%20159%2C%2064%2C%200.2)%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%27rgba(255%2C%20205%2C%2086%2C%200.2)%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%27rgba(75%2C%20192%2C%20192%2C%200.2)%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%27rgba(54%2C%20162%2C%20235%2C%200.2)%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%27rgba(153%2C%20102%2C%20255%2C%200.2)%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%27rgba(201%2C%20203%2C%20207%2C%200.2)%27%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20borderColor%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%27rgb(255%2C%2099%2C%20132)%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%27rgb(255%2C%20159%2C%2064)%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%27rgb(255%2C%20205%2C%2086)%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%27rgb(75%2C%20192%2C%20192)%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%27rgb(54%2C%20162%2C%20235)%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%27rgb(153%2C%20102%2C%20255)%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%27rgb(201%2C%20203%2C%20207)%27%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20borderWidth%3A%201%0A%20%20%7D%5D%0A%7D%2C%0A%20%20options%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20indexAxis%3A%20%27y%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20scales%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20x%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20stacked%3A%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20y%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20stacked%3A%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

I hope can help you.

Comment: This will result into errors since OP is using V3 of chart.js there is no horizontalBar type. With his config he already has a horizontal bar chart because he speciefied indexAxis: 'y' in his options

Comment: You can read https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.2.0/samples/bar/horizontal.html for v3

Comment: Yes, you are using V3 syntax with V2 type so this won't render, as you can see in the link you sent the type is specified as bar and not horizontalBar

Comment: I see, sorry about that, but next maybe you must define more details about your version to use.

Comment: its not my question but the syntax speaks for itself that it is v3 especially with his screenshot that it shows its already horizontal and he only drawed extra bars that he needs